# How to cancel request using merge

Tags: ioexception, retrofit2, rx-android, okhttp

Actually I am using RxAndroid, Retrofit2.0 and Okhttp 3.2.0 in my project.
I am using Observable.merge to call multiple request in order to upload files.
Is there any solution to cancel a unique request ? I know I could use subscription.unsubscribe() but it will cancel all tasks.

I Used okhttp method like client.dispatcher.get(0).cancel() but it throw me an Io Exception like Canceled and it will cancel all tasks.

Do you have a proper way to cancel only a selected request ? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working well. This is the code:

```
                PublishSubject control = PublishSubject.create();
                publishSubjectMap.put(position, control);
                Observable<Response<Upload>> cancellableRestrofitObservable = dropboxapi.uploadImage(requestBody, params, position)
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .takeUntil(control.asObservable());
                observables.add(cancellableRestrofitObservable);


        Observable<Response<Upload>> mergedObservable = Observable.merge(observables);
```

//To cancel 
publishSubjectMap.get(event.getPosition()).onNext("cancel");

Answer (score 0):

You could attach use a `takeUntil(Observable a)`  to each of your constituent Observables and use the "control" observable to selective cancel them. For example

```
PublishSubject<Object> control1 = PublishSubject.create();
PublishSubject<Object> control2 = PublishSubject.create();

Observable<T> cancellableRestrofitObservable1 = retrofitObservable1.takeUntil(control1.asObservable());
Observable<T> cancellableRestrofitObservable2 = retrofitObservable2.takeUntil(control2.asObservable());

Observable<T> mergedObservable = Observable.merge(cancellableRestrofitObservable1,cancellableRestrofitObservable2);

// To cancel retrofitObservable1
control1.onNext("cancel");
```

Comment: Hi John,I want to make lultiple request at the same time